# detect outliers where there are several orders of magnitude in the data

Tags: outliers

I have a data frame consisting of 100 numbers between 0 and 1, 100 values between 100 and 1000, and additionally the numbers 4, 5, 6.

e.g. my data set could be composed of the following unique values:

```
 [1]    0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4    0.5    0.6    0.7    0.8    0.9    4.0 
        5.0    6.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  400.0  500.0  600.0  700.0  800.0
```

Such that the numbers between 0 and 1 occur 100 times (with repetitions), and the same for the numbers larger than 100. The numbers 4, 5, 6 occur only once each.

I would like to be able to automatically detect the numbers 4,5,6, which I would consider outliers to the other data points due to their low occurrence rate.

Is there any method of detecting such outliers?

Comment: if you formalize the DGP, then a model based cluterer should be able to solve this problem (for example as a mix of two distributions).

Comment: Often these would be called "inliers."  Regardless, your question seems to specify exactly how you would detect them: they have "low occurrence rates."  Could you clarify what, beyond this trivial observation, you might be looking for in an answer?

Comment: I on purpose "engineered" this example to be very obvious to the eye, but the fact is I would like to find an automatic way to detect "inliers" in cases where it is not so obvious that a couple of observations are very far from the rest. Here I chose different orders of magnitude.

Comment: Maybe the good way is to split your data (values > 50, values < 50) and detect outliers in sub-samples separately.

Comment: yes but how do you automatically find the splitting criterion?

Comment: Occurrence rates pay no attention to the values.  Are you trying to say that your actual data do not exhibit much variation in occurrence rates?  If so, then you need to be much more specific about what an "inlier" might possibly mean.  If not, then I must reiterate my previous query: what's the matter with identifying the values that appear unusually less often than others as being inliers?

Comment: I will try to explain myself better: the naked eye can detect 2 groups: the one between 0 and 1 and the one between 100 and 1000. The values 4,5,6 seem not to belong to either one, because they are too few and far from each group. What I want to do is find a way to automatically detect them as such.